# How to use IMouse in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

C#, FierFox, Selenium v3.8 
My purpose is movement cursor emulation in browser, using IMouse.MouseMove. Google searching gives me something like that, but I always receive System.NullReferenceException.How I should to use IMouse interface?

Simple console app:

```
    FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\bin\\");
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
    IWebDriver FF = new FirefoxDriver(service);
    FF.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ru/");

    IWebElement element = FF.FindElement(By.Name("btnK"));

    Actions act = new Actions(FF);
    act.MoveToElement(element).Perform(); // It's OK

    ILocatable hoverItem = (ILocatable)element;
    IMouse mouse = ((IHasInputDevices)FF).Mouse;
    mouse.MouseMove(hoverItem.Coordinates, 100, 100); // System.NullReferenceException


    FF.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't do that in the .NET bindings. The `IKeyboard` and `IMouse` interfaces aren't intended to be used by users' code. This is despite the fact that they're public, and do have documentation. What you're running into is that those interfaces will not work for drivers that implement the W3C WebDriver specification. At the moment, that list is Firefox and IE (when using version 3.5 or later of the IE driver), but that list is going to grow to include Chrome and Edge soon, and eventually Safari too. The appropriate way to simulate mouse movement with the .NET bindings is through using the `Actions` class.